# Scroll horizontally to child div on button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried many example for this but I couldn't seem to be able to accomplish this
I have the following set of div's inside a parent as so

[image]

what I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the desired element the parent container should scroll to that element as such

[image]

taking into consideration that each element has it's own width depending on the text

what I tried to do is the following

```
    tabsChanged = (tabIndex: any) => {

    let gparent = document.querySelector("div[data-testid='tabslistMenu']");
    if (gparent) {
      let parent: any = gparent.querySelector("div[role='tablist']");
      let child = document.getElementById("default-tabs-" + tabIndex);
      if (child) {
         const parentleft = parent.scrollLeft;
         const currentPos = child.getBoundingClientRect().left;
         let scrollLeft = currentPos + parentleft;
         scrollLeft -= 40
        parent.scrollTo({
          left: scrollLeft,
          behavior: "smooth",
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

but this code will only gives me the first screenshot result, but i need to accomplish the second screenshot how can I do this?

the following jsfiddle is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/6kdnhrtp/

Comment: Perhaps post a minimal functioning example snippet with both HTML and JavaScript here

Comment: Instead of `-= 40` I would substract (half of the parent's width - half of the navigation element's width). Because that's where the middle is. You might need to check the left- and rightmost navigation elements to scroll directly to it instead of centering it, depending.

Comment: @PeterKrebs can you give me an example please?

Comment: I already did. Substract (half of the parent's width - half of the navigation element's width). Because that would be the middle, mathematically speaking. I don't have time to write the full code for you, sorry.

Comment: i added a jsfiddle example that may make my problem a bit clearer

Comment: Sora your jsfiddle seems to work, and implements @Peter's solution?

Comment: StackOverflow also has runnable snippets. Use the `<>` button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solve your problem but for me seems to be fine.

```js
function handleClick () {
    const parent = this.parentNode;
  const next = this.nextElementSibling;
  const scrollLeft = this.offsetLeft - (parent.clientWidth - this.clientWidth) / 2;
  parent.scrollLeft = next ? next.offsetLeft : this.offsetLeft;
  parent.scrollTo({
      left: scrollLeft,
      behavior: 'smooth',
  });   
}

const children = document.querySelectorAll('#parent div');
children.forEach((child) => child.onclick = handleClick );
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll
}

#parent div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>Click me to scroll 1</div>
  <div >Click me to scroll 2</div>
  <div>Click me to scroll 3</div>
  <div>Click me to scroll 4</div>
  <div>Click me to scroll 5</div>
  <div>Click me to scroll 6</div>
</div>
```